# Discrete Math creating functions that map sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

contruct a simple one-to-one function from
$Z^+ → P(Z^+)$

How would I approach this type of problem? I'm guessing from utilizing $F: Z^+ → P(Z^+)$ 

I'm guessing need to find some way to map all positive integers to the power set of all positive integers.

Do I just define something like f(x) = the number of elements inside each subset of the Power set ? Thought I'm sure that wouldn't be 1-to-1 because multiple subsets are the same size in the power set.

Comment: It would sure be nice if we could just let $f(n) = n$, but we need a *set* including an integer....

Comment: Because $P(Z^+)$ only contains sets of integers and not the integers themselves no?

Comment: If you set all $Z^+$ as n then would the function just be $2^n$ ?